# Materialize sidenav won't appear

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I am trying to learn Materialize, but I can't get the sidenav to appear when I click on the menu button. I think it has something to do with the initializers.

```
    <body>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
  </ul>
```

script tags at bottom of html body:

```
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Your sidenav() function is not defined

Answer (score 0):

`sidenav()` function is not defined. You should try this instead

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav-trigger').click(function(){
      $('#mobile-demo').removeClass("sidenav");
    });

  });
  </script>
```

Comment: That displayed the content below the menu icon, but without the intended styling or animation.

Answer (score 0):

It was not initializing M, the global object for Materialize. I changed the version of Materialize from the CDN and ran this. I ended up not needing jQuery.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script>
  const sideNav = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
  M.Sidenav.init(sideNav, {});
</script>
```